# Can't manage to stop AJAX from making requests without jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, abort

I'm using AJAX to send the server a score after a game being played and eventually updating the DB if the record has been beaten. This all works fine except when I try to get back a string from a php script which tells if a new record has been set or not. Unfortunately in this project I cannot use jQuery but plain Javascript. My main problem is that apparently the AJAX request is not aborting and thus I get continuos textNodes appended in myDiv. So inside my ajaxHandler function :

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = display;  
function display() {  
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {  
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {  
    var textResp = document.createTextNode(xmlHttp.responseText);
    myDiv.appendChild(textResp);
    xmlHttp.abort();
    } 
    else {  
    window.alert('Could not communicate with server.');
    xmlHttp.abort(); 
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: It means that you are sending requests again and again. It has nothing to do with `xmlHttp.abort();`. Status 200 means that request has successfully completed, at this point `abort()` makes no sense (and effect). You probably have some sort of interval that you are not clearing.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. I did not have any intervals set. I solved the problem by simply removing xmlHttp.abort() line and adding a return.